# Serverprocesses ending with '-d'?

Tags: server, process

I just realized, that every serverprocess ends with a d?
Like:

- Apache: httpd
- MySQL : mysqld
- Unreal IRC : unrealircd

Why is this? Is there any reason, or is it to recognize them from each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a convention for programs that run in the background to perform a task.

It means [Daemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29) - inspired by Maxwell's Daemon, an imaginary creature from the world of physics charged with reversing entropy by sorting molecules.

Comment: Unix's answer to a Windows Service?

Comment: Essentially the same arrangement, yes. Daemons are usually started by "init", the first process to start on a Unix system.